# What tag should I use if my question is about verse placement in English translations, not the translations themselves?

Tags: support, specific-question, questions

In asking question on the BHSE, I noticed that there is no clear tag to use when asking questions about verse placement in English translations of the original languages. What tag should I use?

For example in the English, Hosea 7:1 is the second half of a sentence separated by a "comma" from 6:11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand what you mean by "verse placement." I believe you may mean *where*/*why* verses are chosen to be "broken" at that point in the text in relation to the original language texts (that were originally not broken into verses).

If so, then this still relates some to "translation" (the translating of the original text to the English, including "breaking" into verses). If you are interested in the decision making *reasoning* behind that, then [translation-philosophy](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-philosophy) might apply. I could also see [bible-versions](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-versions) or a specific form of that (e.g. [kjv](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kjv)) might apply. Additionally, [history](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) includes the history of the "biblical text itself," so that would apply to the addition of versification.

NOTE: The example that was added shows why specific English translations (and tags for such) may be relevant, because it is not just a versification issue, but a punctuation issue as well. The example gives a good case:

- NIV and ESV have a comma ending Hos 6:11
- KJV, NKJV, and NASB have a period ending Hos 6:11

So the question may be just as relevant as to why some used a comma and others used a period at that point. (The versification tends to stay "traditional" to what was already done previously in English translations, but not all versions may agree that verse and chapter breaks should have occurred where they did, and so punctuation may vary.)

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @WnGatRC456 That was a good example, and I tweaked my answer based on it.

Comment: Great now I know what to use

Comment: "versification" could be another good tag.